# How to do xml parsing in store procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a table which contains xml format request.
For eg:

```
Api_id xmlRequest  Sent_Time
1      ........    07-04-2016 10:07:12:345
1      ........    08-04-2016 10:03:12:345
2      ........    09-04-2016 10:08:12:345
2      ........    09-04-2016 10:09:12:345
```

For Api_id, we can have multiple request.

XML request schema is same, but has different values. 
Xml request is as :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
      <COST> 123.00</COST>
   </PART>
</PARTS>
```

I need store procedure, so I can send API_id, and value(which i can search in xml request )  and get xml requests based on Item value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getxmlRequest(
        @Api_Id INT
        @value
       ,@xmlRequest VARCHAR(max) out)
AS
BEGIN
        Set @xmlRequest = SELECT xmlRequest FROM Api_request
          WHERE Api_id = @Api_id
        /* here need to iterate over @xmlRequest */  
              Set @Xmlvalue = SELECT X.R.value ('.','nvarchar (150)')
                     FROM  @xmlRequest.nodes(XPATH) X(R)
              if(@XmlValue = @value)
                 /*Add to result so i can return 
        /*I want to return all @xmlRequest if we has value from  xpath*/              
END;
```

So my question If

```
Set @xmlRequest = SELECT xmlRequest FROM Api_request
              WHERE Api_id = @Api_id
```

If we will get multiple result : does it possible to iterate? If yes how efficient i can ?

How to return multiple @xmlRequest as Api_id is same?

Does any one work on such kind of scenario? Please help me.

Comment: Is the XML in your table already XML typed or is this VARCHAR (asking due to the `<!DOCTYPE ...>`) ?

Comment: @Shnugo : xmlRequest field is VARCHAR type.

Comment: Why do you want to use a stored procedure if you do nothing more than to  *read* data? Use a TVF or a VIEW... And further: Your example does not clearify, what you are searching for. The pseudo code wouldn't even compile. What are the parameters your are passing in?

Comment: @Shnugo: Thanks for helping me. In store proc , as I mentioned I will do parsing, As its huge data and will java to call this proc. In java It can be a painful to call different query each time. I am searching for xmlRequest field from DB. I will pass Id and value, Using Id, I will get xml request. For eg: let say 3 xml request. Now Using value input I will check each xml request and and return  xmlRequest only if that Xml contains value.

Comment: Contains value *anywhere* ? Even parts of it?

Comment: For that I will use xpath. So no worries.

Comment: Do you know that you cannot use dynamically defined XPath (unless you go with dynamic SQL and `EXEC`)? XQuery allows some generic approaches but this is limited... Did you check my answer?

Comment: Do you looking for - return all the xmlRequest where ITEM = ? and Api_id = ?Api_id , rgt?

Comment: Hi @Somu, is this question still open? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT *,CONVERT(XML,xmlRequest,2) 
FROM Api_request
WHERE Api_id = @Api_id 
    AND CONVERT(XML,xmlRequest,2).value('(/PARTS/PART/ITEM)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
        LIKE '%'+@value+'%'
```

It will return all the xmlRequest where  contains your value

Comment: The OP mentioned in a comment, that the xmlRequest column is of type `VARCHAR` you will not be allowed to use `.value()` there...

Comment: Then he can simply convert that string to XML (ie cast(xmlRequest as xml).value('(/PARTS/PART/ITEM)[1]','nvarchar(max)')  LIKE '%CPU%' )

Comment: Just try it with the original data ;-)

Comment: Sure, I knew that. The same call to CONVERT is in my answer.  We just did not know which element keeps the data the OP wants to search for. One hint: test your suggestions ...

Answer (score -1):

Your question is quite unclear, but please have look on this:

```
CREATE TABLE #testTbl(Api_id INT, xmlRequest VARCHAR(MAX), SentTime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #testTbl VALUES
 (1,'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
      <COST> 123.00</COST>
   </PART>
</PARTS>',GETDATE())
,(1,'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>CPU</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>INTEL</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>CPUModelXY</MODEL>
      <COST>345.00</COST>
   </PART>
</PARTS>',GETDATE())
,(2,'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<PARTS>
   <TITLE>Car Parts</TITLE>
   <PART>
      <ITEM>Wheel</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>Pirelli</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>WheelModelXY</MODEL>
      <COST>100.00</COST>
   </PART>
</PARTS>',GETDATE());
```

This will rerturn all rows where the Api_id=1

```
SELECT Api_id
      ,CONVERT(XML,xmlRequest,2) AS xmlRequest
      ,SentTime  
FROM #testTbl
WHERE Api_id=1;
```

This will return table-like data. You can use "normal" SQL (WHERE, GROUP BY, ...) to continue

```
DECLARE @Api_Id INT=NULL;

WITH MyRequests AS
(
    SELECT Api_id
          ,RealXML.value('(/PARTS/TITLE)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Title
          ,part.value('ITEM[1]','varchar(max)') AS Item
          ,part.value('MANUFACTURER[1]','varchar(max)') AS Manufacturer
          ,part.value('MODEL[1]','varchar(max)') AS Model
          ,part.value('COST[1]','decimal(12,4)') AS Cost
          ,SentTime  
    FROM #testTbl
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONVERT(XML,xmlRequest,2) AS RealXML) AS ConvertedToXML
    CROSS APPLY RealXML.nodes('/PARTS/PART') AS A(part)
    WHERE @ApiId IS NULL OR Api_Id=@Api_Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM MyRequests
--WHERE ...
--GROUP BY ...
--ORDER ...
;
```

The result

```
+---+----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
| 1 | Computer Parts | Motherboard | ASUS    | P3B-F        | 123.0000 | 2016-04-07 11:54:08.980 |
+---+----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
| 1 | Computer Parts | CPU         | INTEL   | CPUModelXY   | 345.0000 | 2016-04-07 11:54:08.980 |
+---+----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
| 2 | Car Parts      | Wheel       | Pirelli | WheelModelXY | 100.0000 | 2016-04-07 11:54:08.980 |
+---+----------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

Clean Up

```
GO
DROP TABLE #testTbl;
```